# Creating a Spark DataFrame from an RDD of lists

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have an rdd (we can call it myrdd) where each record in the rdd is of the form:

```
[('column 1',value), ('column 2',value), ('column 3',value), ... , ('column 100',value)]
```

I would like to convert this into a DataFrame in pyspark - what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your question where you're having trouble. Is it the fact that you have so many columns? Or just that records of your RDD are lists of tuples?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about use the `toDF` method? You only need add the field names.

```
df = rdd.toDF(['column', 'value'])
```

Comment: this answer works, and the solution I posted below (based on your answer) would convert an rdd as described above to a DataFrame

Comment: what if you dont know the column names or want to use columns of some other dataframe ? related question from me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882076/update-some-rows-of-a-dataframe-or-create-new-dataframe-in-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment125309949_70882076

Answer (score 15):

The answer by @dapangmao got me to this solution:

```
my_df = my_rdd.map(lambda l: Row(**dict(l))).toDF()
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [DataFrame documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds) to make this example work for you, but this should work. I'm assuming your RDD is called `my_rdd`

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# You have a ton of columns and each one should be an argument to Row
# Use a dictionary comprehension to make this easier
def record_to_row(record):
    schema = {'column{i:d}'.format(i = col_idx):record[col_idx] for col_idx in range(1,100+1)}
    return Row(**schema)


row_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda x: record_to_row(x))

# Now infer the schema and you have a DataFrame
schema_my_rdd = sqlContext.inferSchema(row_rdd)

# Now you have a DataFrame you can register as a table
schema_my_rdd.registerTempTable("my_table")
```

I haven't worked much with DataFrames in Spark but this should do the trick

Comment: you might need to add a line after the sqlContext is created to load the implicits library: "import sqlContext .implicits._".  See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: Isn't that a scala-only thing? My answer is written in Python

Comment: I got: `AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'inferSchema'`

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, let's say you have a dataframe named as **userDF**.

```
>>> type(userDF)
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

Lets just convert it to RDD (

```
userRDD = userDF.rdd
>>> type(userRDD)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

and now you can do some manipulations and call for example map function :

```
newRDD = userRDD.map(lambda x:{"food":x['favorite_food'], "name":x['name']})
```

Finally, lets create a DataFrame from resilient distributed dataset (**RDD**).

```
newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRDD, ["food", "name"])

>>> type(ffDF)
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

That's all.

I was hitting this warning message before when I tried to call :

```
newDF = sc.parallelize(newRDD, ["food","name"] : 

.../spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:336: UserWarning: Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated. Use pyspark.sql.Row inst  warnings.warn("Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated. "
```

So no need to do this anymore...

Comment: what to do if each row has plenty of columns, and potentially each row is different in definition?