# Update some rows of a dataframe or create new dataframe in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to PySpark and my objective is to use PySpark script in AWS Glue for:

1. reading a dataframe from input file in Glue => done
2. changing columns of some rows which satisfy a condition => facing issue
3. write the updated dataframe on the same schema into S3 => done

The task seems very simple, but I could not find a way to complete it and still facing different different issues with my changing code.

Till now, my code looks like this:

```
Transform2.printSchema() # input schema after reading 
Transform2 = Transform2.toDF()
def updateRow(row):
    # my logic to update row based on a global condition 
    #if row["primaryKey"]=="knownKey": row["otherAttribute"]= None
    return row

LocalTransform3 = [] # creating new dataframe from Transform2 
for row in Transform2.rdd.collect():
    row = row.asDict()
    row = updateRow(row)
    LocalTransform3.append(row)
print(len(LocalTransform3))

columns = Transform2.columns
Transform3 = spark.createDataFrame(LocalTransform3).toDF(*columns)
print('Transform3 count', Transform3.count())
Transform3.printSchema()
Transform3.show(1,truncate=False)

Transform4 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(Transform3, glueContext, "Transform3")
print('Transform4 count', Transform4.count())
```

I tried using multiple things like:

- using map to update existing rows in a lambda
- using collect()
- using createDataFrame() to create new dataframe

But faced errors in below steps:

- not able to create new updated rdd
- not able to create new dataframe from rdd using existing columns

Some errors in Glue I got, at different stages:

- ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
- ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling
- An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. Traceback (most recent call last):

Any working code snippet or help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the transformation you want to do on your rows?

Comment: if row["primaryKey"]=="knownKey":
     row["otherAttribute"]= None

Comment: And which column should holy "knownKey" / None?

Comment: my logic is: for some input primary keys, make other column as None for rows of these primary keys

Comment: So everything should be None if a row has a knownKey in the Primary Key column?

Comment: No. only a particular attribute ("otherAttribute") will be None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when

Transform2 = Transform2.toDF()
withKeyMapping = Transform2.withColumn('otherAttribute', when(col("primaryKey") == "knownKey", lit(None)).otherwise(col('otherAttribute')))
```

This should work for your use-case.

Comment: Hi Robert, my one usecase is that the 'otherAttribute' is an attribute inside an array attribute 'arrayAttribute'. Now I want to make 'otherAttribute' as None for all items of  'arrayAttribute'. Is there any way to do it the way you have suggested ?

Comment: This is a different question. If this helped you please upvote & accepted and open up another question.

Comment: sure. your answer provided me a way to tackle it